# Cannot right click on an element from Dev Tools after opening a div element

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge-chromium

I am facing a critical situation regarding my option to right-click on an element from Dev Tools. At some point, the application refuses to allow the action of right-clicking on any element from the Elements tab after inspecting something from the web page. In other words, I can't right-click on any element.

I can right-click on any other thing such as button, console line, source line, but NOT element.
I tried disabling Javascript from the page and nothing, I tried other browsers such as Edge and nothing, I tried clearing the cache and nothing, I tried removing all extensions and nothing.

I found only 2 temporary solutions, but only for a couple of hours until it breaks again:

1. fully remove any Google application from the PC and reinstall them;
2. open Google Chrome / Microsoft Edge as Guest.

Steps to reproduce:

1. open Google Chrome with the logged user on the browser;
2. access a page such as Facebook or Youtube;
3. log in to the selected web page;
4. inspect an element from the page: a button, or an image;
5. attempt to right-click the element from Dev Tools.

Thank you!

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome/Chromium. Use an older/newer version of the browser.